# Noetherian ring under some conditions has at least two minimal prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-domain, noetherian, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Question is :

> Suppose $R$ is a noetherian ring. Prove that $R$ is either an integral domain, has nonzero nilpotent elements, or has at least two minimal prime ideals. [Use the previous exercise.]

Previous exercise says :
 Let $\mathfrak{p}_1, \mathfrak{p}_2,\cdots \mathfrak{p}_n$ be the associated prime ideals of the ideal $(0)$ in the Noetherian ring $R$.

1. Show that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i$ is the collection of nilpotent elements in $R$.
2. Show that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i$ is the collection of zero divisors in $R$.

I do not really understand the question clearly... If $R$ is integral domain, there would be no nonzero  nilpotent elements. So, what does he mean when he say "either an integral domain, has nonzero nilpotent elements". May be i am missing some point...

Suppose $R$ is not an integral domain and do not have  non zero nilpotent elements..

This means that  $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i=\{0\}$ and $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i\neq \{0\}$

i could not see  how to  conclude from this that $R$ has at least two minimal prime ideals..

Please give some hints...

This is an exercise from Dummit and Foote's ABSTRACT ALGEBRA, Section $15.2$.

Comment: He's not claiming that all three of these things happen at once, and later on you seem to understand that.

Comment: Anyway, to the problem itself: I think you have a good start. Now, every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal, and the minimal prime ideals are always among the associated primes. Take a look at this intersection $\bigcap \mathfrak{p}_i$ -- what would this look like if there were only one minimal prime?

Comment: I am not thinking all three of these things happen at once.. what  does he want to say actually?

Comment: @Hoot : If there is only one minimal prime then we would have $\mathfrak{p}=(0)$ i.e., zero ideal is prime ideal which would mean $R$ is an integral domain a contradiction....

Comment: It's not an amazing piece of english, but you seem to have interpreted the question correctly later — what's the issue? Maybe it would be better to say, "at least one of the following holds: (1) R is a domain (2) R has nonzero nilpotents (3) R has at least two minimal prime ideals". Of course, you could say something even stronger.

Comment: Right! So you're done. Really the $\bigcup \mathfrak{p}_i$ isn't so useful here.

Comment: @Hoot : Thanks for your help.. I have one more doubt... a minimal prime ideal is a prime ideal P such that there is no other prime ideal Q strictly contained in P....   In your second comment i understand  "every prime ideal contains a minimal prime ideal," but do not understand next sentence "and the minimal prime ideals are always among the associated primes".. Associated primes are corresponding to some paticular ideal and minimal prime ideals are related to the ring itself... how to relate these two?

Comment: I guess I don't really use this older language so I'm probably saying confusing things. To me what you call associated primes of $0$ I would just call associated primes of $R$. Then my assertion at least looks plausible. I don't know if D-F prove this but it really should be one of the first things that's checked.

Comment: What you write seems to indicate that the radical of $(0)$ is each minimal prime $\mathfrak{p}$, which doesn't seem to make sense. Anyway, this approach has been totally trumped in the answers below, but I do think this is a basic fact about associated primes. If I find time to download D&F later and match everything up with their definitions then I'll try to write an answer explaining all of this.

Comment: @Hoot : what i was told was nonsense..... i will correct myself and write here...

Comment: Let $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal then by "a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ contains the ideal $\mathfrak{a}$ if and only if $\mathfrak{p}$ contains one of the associated primes of a minimal primary decomposition of $\mathfrak{a}$" this $\mathfrak{p}$ contains an associated prime say $\mathfrak{q}$ of $(0)$. As $\mathfrak{p}$ itself is minimal and $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal containing $(0)$ we should have $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}$.. So, minimal primes are always among the associated primes... I guess this is what you mean.. @Hoot

Comment: Does the book assume that $R \ne 0$? The zero ring doesn't satisfy any of the given properties.

Comment: Yes, all rings are commutative with $1$.. So, ring is nonzero.... @AymanHourieh

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the zero ring is commutative with $1$. It just happens that $0 = 1$. I don't have the book next to me. I guess it assumes $0 \ne 1$ at the beginning of the chapter.

Comment: yes yes it assumes $1\neq 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits to this answer goes to the user https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127490/hoot

Let $R$ be a noetherian ring so that i can assume that $(0)$ has a primary decomposition.

Let $\mathfrak{p}_1, \mathfrak{p}_2,\cdots \mathfrak{p}_n$ be the associated prime ideals of the ideal $(0)$ in the Noetherian ring $R$. Then

1. $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i$ is the collection of nilpotent elements in $R$.
2. $\bigcup_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i$ is the collection of zero divisors in $R$.

Suppose $R$ is not an integral domain and has no nonzero nilpotent elements then we see that $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i=(0)$...

Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal associated prime of $(0)$ and $\mathfrak{q}$ be a minimal prime ideal in $R$ such that $\mathfrak{q}\subset\mathfrak{p}$.. As $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal, $\mathfrak{q}$ must contain some minimal associated  prime say $\mathfrak{l}$ of $(0)$. So, we have $\mathfrak{l}\subset\mathfrak{q}\subset\mathfrak{p}$. AS $\mathfrak{p}$ and $\mathfrak{l}$ are associated primes of $(0)$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal we  should have $\mathfrak{l}=\mathfrak{q}=\mathfrak{p}$.. Thus $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal...

Suppose $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal prime ideal then, there exist a  minimal associated prime  $\mathfrak{q}$ of $(0)$ such that $\mathfrak{p}\supset \mathfrak{q}$. As $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal and $\mathfrak{p}$ is minimal prime ideal we should have $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{q}$... So, $\mathfrak{p}$ is a minimal associated prime.. So, minimal prime ideal is minimal associated prime of $(0)$..

So, minimal primes are precisely the minimal associated primes... So,
$$\{0\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i=\bigcap_{\rm{minimal}}\mathfrak{p}_i=\bigcap_{\rm{minimal~ primes ~ of ~ R}}\mathfrak{q}_i$$

So, intersection of all minimal prime ideals is $\{0\}$ and if there is only one minimal prime ideal then that ideal has to be zero ideal... As zero ideal is prime ideal in this $R$, the ring has to be an integral domain which contradicts the assumption.. thus, there exists atleast two minimal prime ideals..

We have $\mathfrak{q}\supset (0)=\mathfrak{q}_1\cap \mathfrak{q}_2\cap\cdots\cap \mathfrak{q}_n$ which implies $r(\mathfrak{q})\supset r(\mathfrak{q}_1)\cap r(\mathfrak{q}_2)\cap\cdots\cap r(\mathfrak{q}_n)$ . As $\mathfrak{q}$ is a prime ideal we have $r(\mathfrak{q})=\mathfrak{q}$... This would mean $\mathfrak{q}\supset r(\mathfrak{q}_1)\cap r(\mathfrak{q}_2)\cap\cdots\cap r(\mathfrak{q}_n)$.. This imply $\mathfrak{q}$ contains some $r(\mathfrak{q}_i)$ for some $i$ and we may even assume $r(\mathfrak{q}_i)$ is minimal primary component...  Here i have used a result that "$\mathfrak{a}_1,\mathfrak{a}_2,\cdots, \mathfrak{a}_n$ be ideals of $A$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal containing $\bigcap_{i=1}^n \mathfrak{a}_i$. 
 Then $\mathfrak{p}\supseteq \mathfrak{a}_i$ for some $i$".

Answer (score 1):

Note that for the given statement to be true, we have to assume that the ring is non-zero. Furthermore, the Noetherian hypothesis is superfluous. I think the following solution is far simpler than the book's hint.

Suppose $R$ is not an integral domain and does not contain non-zero nilpotent elements. Then we can find $a, b \in R - \{0\}$ such that $ab = 0$. Since $a$ is not nilpotent, we can find a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ such that $a \not \in \mathfrak p$. Similarly, we can find a minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ such that $b \not \in \mathfrak q$. It cannot be the case that $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak q$, for otherwise we would have $ab \in \mathfrak p$ but neither $a \in \mathfrak p$ nor $b \in \mathfrak p$.

Comment: Yes Yes... This is far more simpler than the books hint... Some times giving a hint make you think in that way only :D.... May be they want to make use of the previous exercise... Thank you anyways :)

Comment: I have accepted this answer but then i thought may be this is not what i was looking for... i was not looking for another way of solving this but to use the hints that are given... Thank you again :)

Comment: Noetherian assumption is superflous but as it was asking to use previous exercise in whihc there was a decomposition for ideal $(0)$ noetherian condition was imposed just to make sure that some primary decomposition of ideal $(0)$ exists....

Comment: Dear @Praphulla, I understand this. I just wanted my answer to be self-contained.